# Rare Uncaught ReferenceError using JQuery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my site javascript error log, it seems like I have a rare race condition, but I cannot see how it can happen.

I have 3 script (2 custom) all loaded from the head of the HTML

```
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
   <script src="common.js"></script>
</head>
```

main.js contains getPosZoom() and common.js contains getCookie()

Later in the HTML document (last thing in the body tag) I am using JQuery document ready to trigger getPosZoom()

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    getPosZoom(...);
}
```

getPosZoom will call function getCookie.

Sometimes getCookie is not defined, here is a case from my log

```
2020-08-20 00:20:31: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js | Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined    
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.126 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
+http://www.google.com/bot.html)    
Stacktrace: ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
    at getPosZoom (https://example.com/main.js:162:2)
    at HTMLDocument. (https://example.com:105:13)
    at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307) | line: 2
```

How can this happen?

Comment: I now see the agent is Googlebot, could it be, that the crawler doesn't behave like a real browser. I have read that Google indexes dynamic/javascript content just fine.

Comment: Where is your `$(document).ready` call? Is it inside `main.js`?

Comment: No, it is placed in the body part of the HTML